# Splitting a single variable dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-munging

I have a CSV file that appears as just one variable. I want to split it to 6. I need help.

```
str(nyt_data)
'data.frame':   3104 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Article_ID.Date.Title.Subject.Topic.Code: Factor w/ 3104 levels "16833;7-Dec-03;Ruse in Toyland: Chinese Workers' Hidden Woe;Chinese Workers Hide Woes for American Inspectors;5",..: 2420 2421 2422 2423 2424 2425 2426 2427 2428 2429 ...

nyt_data$Article_ID.Date.Title.Subject.Topic.Code
```

The result displaced after the above line of code is:

```
> head(nyt_data$Article_ID.Date.Title.Subject.Topic.Code)
[1] 41246;1-Jan-96;Nation's Smaller Jails Struggle To Cope With Surge in Inmates;Jails overwhelmed with hardened criminals;12                                                                          
[2] 41257;2-Jan-96;FEDERAL IMPASSE SADDLING STATES WITH INDECISION;Federal budget impasse affect on states;20                                                                                          
[3] 41268;3-Jan-96;Long, Costly Prelude Does Little To Alter Plot of Presidential Race;Contenders for 1996 Presedential elections;20
```

Please help me with code to split these into 6 separate columns `Article_ID`, `Date`, `Title`, `Subject`, `Topic`, `Code`.

Comment: it's not a "Comma Seperated Value" CSV, use special delimiter. Per monhawk below.

Answer (score 2):

The data is split with ";" but read.csv defaults to ",". Simply do the following:

```
df <- read.csv(data, sep = ";")
```

Comment: I am having errors after using that code: nyt_data <- read_csv("nyt_data.csv", sep = ";")
Error in read_csv("nyt_data.csv", sep = ";") : 
  unused argument (sep = ";")
>

Comment: The problem was because the colnames header was separated with a dot instead with ; so I went to the csv file to change the dots to ; before using the code to import and separate the colnames. But again not every data was separated into their colnames accordingly. Some rows fell into the first column only. Do you have any idea why its so?

Comment: Can you post an example row that didnt split? Also, post the row before and after the row that doesnt split.

Answer (score 2):

Just read CSV file with custom [`sep`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html).

Like this:

```
data <- read.csv(input_file, sep=';')
```

Comment: I tried this also. But not every row did split correctly. Do you know why please? Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Instructius Can you show which rows are incorrect? Maybe you need a custom `quote` and `dec` parameters.